# How to Secure WebAPI with Single-Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorization, single-page-application

I'm building an application with an MVC4 single-page front end and a WebAPI on another machine that returns json query data directly to the browser. The authentication happens on the MVC side where a user object is built that defines a set of "canDoX" permissions for the current user.

The problem is how do I secure access to the WebAPI actions based on those permissions without re-authenticating and authorizing the user all over again when it receives the request from the page .js.

As it stands, the user would have to know about the api, but if they did they could hack the url and query whatever data they want by `'/api/myController/myRestrictedAction/123'`

Any ideas? Should I scrap the single-page idea and just call the webAPI from the MVC controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP is stateless.  You must perform authorization and authentication on every request and this often happens many times per page access for various resources on that page.

Per your example, `'/api/myController/myRestrictedAction/123'` is a resource that you are exposing to someone.  Whether or not the user accessing that resource should be able to access it is up to you to decide.

Instead of thinking of a user accessing random endpoints as "hacking the url", it is really a bug in your application that allowed a user to request and access something that he should not be able to access.